# Clickable Row & Checkbox conflict

Tags: jquery, checkbox, clickable

I made my table row clickable with this function

```
    $("#grid tbody tr").click(function () {
    var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
    $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

and it works fine, however when I try to click the checkbox self, it doesnt work.
What should I do to make both of them work?

Comment: I try to click the checkbox self??? means

Comment: why do you need to override the default browser function??

Comment: He wants to make clicking the row toggle the checkbox. Basically like a huge label.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using a single event handler:

```
$("#grid tbody tr").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.type == "checkbox") {

        // stop the bubbling to prevent firing the row's click event
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
        $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/UX2Fv/

Comment: is it possible to leave 1 checkbox always selected? I dont want to toggle the last checkbox **[http://jsfiddle.net/uPqXf/](http://jsfiddle.net/uPqXf/)**

Comment: For newer jQuery use the `prop` attribute: `$checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));`   `attr` may fail.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#grid tbody tr input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Then clicking the checkbox will not trigger a click event on the tr.

Comment: is it possible to leave 1 checkbox always selected? I dont want to toggle the last checkbox **[http://jsfiddle.net/uPqXf/](http://jsfiddle.net/uPqXf/)**

Answer (score 3):

better u can do this with simple HTML, write  `for` attribute in `label`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"><label for="myCheck">CheckThis</label>
                              ^                   ^
```

**Note**: `id` of `<input type="checkbox"` would be value of `for` attribute in `<label>`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UX2Fv/1/)

Comment: how to you put that `^` below text??

Comment: @experimentX  simple: `SHIFT+6`

Comment: hmmm also very useful and simple

Comment: This doesn't make the entire row clickable, only the label text.

Answer (score 0):

These answers all work fine, but I was stuck for a long while trying to figure out why I couldn't get them to work. I was generating my table rows dynamically and they didn't exist on the DOM yet. For this reason, none of the solutions worked.

What solved this for me was to use the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```
$('body').on('click', '#grid tbody  tr', function (e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#grid tbody tr input:checked').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```